# How are simple Objects and Arrays passed?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, silverlight, marshalling

I'm a bit confused about the conversion mechanism responsible for transforming simple Javascript objects and arrays in to "managed type" (for brevity, C#) objects.

The first section of the [Microsoft article concerning this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645079%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) states (or seems to imply) that the conversion is implicit and automatic:

> - JavaScript arrays are converted to object[].
> - JavaScript dictionaries are converted to Dictionary.

However, subsequent sections seem to mention the necessity of the helper `create` and `createObject` functions for the conversion:

Arrays:

> **Array and List Types**
>
> The default is **explicit by-value marshaling** from JavaScript to managed code.
>   Automatic JSON serialization to managed input parameters is not supported.
>   Instead, you must explicitly use creatable types or the create helper methods.
>
> ```
>  ...
>  ...
> ```
>
> **By-Value Marshaling**
>
> If you want to pass a JavaScript array by value to managed code, the
>   target .NET Framework property or input parameter must be typed as
>   something other than ScriptObject. You must then use one of the **create**
>   or **createObject** helper methods to explicitly force a conversion from
>   the JavaScript array to a .NET Framework list or array type.

(There is an almost identical pair of clauses for "Dictionaries and Custom Types")

Is there something I'm missing, or is the documentation contradictory? Is conversion implicit and automatic for simple objects and arrays or not? If so, what objects do the latter clauses apply to? If not, why are they mentioned among the primitive Javascript types that are converted implicitly?

Answer (score 1):

1) The answer is covered in the article. A paragraph you did not quote.

> The JavaScript dictionary will be recursively marshaled by value onto
>   the target .NET Framework type. Silverlight will use the JSON
>   serializer to deserialize from a JavaScript dictionary onto a
>   conforming .NET Framework custom type or dictionary.

2) Because a custom type may be inside a known type. 
If you are such a heretic, .net makes sure you can bypass conversion at will. I say heretic, as if so, why use json in the first place? =)

Just let it slide..

Comment: 1) If I'm not mistaken, I believe the paragraph you quoted merely details the mechanism of the marshalling operation AFTER its been initiated. It makes no mention of the described process being the result of an automatic impetus or the result of an explicit call to  create() or createObject(). 2) Ah, I see.

Comment: I would add that if I ever had to send a bunch of bytes that cannot be parsed to/from json, I would consider that aspect a part of the architecture and within the project scope, and I would not delegate that to a custom serializing class. Prolly deal with as base64 and handle it in code.